# Android Navigation and activities (determine which activity is parent)

Tags: android

I have three activities: A, B, C
From both Activities A,B I can call

```
    startActivity(new Intent(this, C.class));
```

So the logic would be something like A->B->C or A->C .. now when I am in C, I would like to get back to B or A depending on from which activity was C started.

Now the question is, when I am in Activity C, how to get "Back" to the parent activity, from which I opened this activity C?

I have been trying something with **`NavUtils`** and **`Intent.FLAGS`**, but I was not successful.

BTW: I can not use `finish()` or `onBackPressed()`. I am using custom dynamic created theme in my app and when I use `onBackPressed()` it will show a default application theme (default white screen with icon) before the desired activity is loaded.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you want to get back to parent programmatically or do you want to get back when the user press `back button`?

Comment: I want to get back to parent when user either press the `back button` or the `up button` from the `ActionBar`. So basically both, but if its programatically then its fine for me. I can always override the `onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your manifest add this to activity C so this part solves the back button.

```
 <activity
            android:name="your.package.name.C"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
 </activity>
```

lets solve up button:

you must use `putExtra` that indicates the parent of `C activity`. for example when you want to call it from activity B do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this,C.class);          
                i.putExtra(MY_PARENT,"B");  
                startActivity(i);
```

and in `activity C` store `MY_PARENT` value in a string called `parent`. then when the user press `UP button` read that and go to the parent.
that means in activity C :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent i = new Intent(C.this,Class.forName(parent));                
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, Thank you very much! But the thing is that it only resolves the problem with choosing the parent activity. Which I was already able to reach with the NavUtils.
My problem is probably somewhere else. I have two themes (dark and white) where white theme is default. When I switch to dark theme and  `finish()` any activity, for a while there is a white screen with empty default layout before the dark one is loaded.

Comment: Btw when I use the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` line in the activity Manifest. this default white screen shows up as well when I switch in the C activity. It has something to do with that launch mode, because when I erase it the dark theme remains and there is no white default screen before the activity starts.

Comment: even better would be to use:`intent.putExtra("MY_PARENT",this.getClass().getName());`

Answer (score 0):

You may create and process too many objects in `onCreate` method of your `Activity`, so that causes the delay that you see before the desired activity get loaded...

You can do all those creation and processing in an `AsyncTask` and keep your `onCreate` method clean, then you won't see that delay anymore.

Comment: Not really, The first thing I am doing is changing the theme (even before calling `super.OnCreate()`). Only things I am doing in the activity is accessing the action bar and changing the title that is it. I don't actually know why there is the mentioned delay. Most probably it is caused by changing the application theme. It seems to me it always shows the default theme before the activity is loaded.